# Rails Param Troubles - old vs new data

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4

When I send form data in my rails application, I need to perform a function using both the original value AND the newly submitted value. Is there any way, upon submit, that I can carry over both the original value and the newly input one to be used in the controller?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Two choices:

1. Add a hidden input field with the old value in your form
2. If you are using an ActiveRecord model and your form is changing
   values on that model, you can use @person.changes to see a list
   properties with their old and new value.  See
   http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty/changes